# Filter collection by multiple attributes with OR not AND

Tags: collection, multiselect-attribute

Trying to filter a collection to show results where attribute_1 = something OR attribute_2 = something. I can get it to filter by one or the other, but not if one is true OR the other is true.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_1');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_2');

$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
array("attribute"=>"attribute_1","eq"=>"something"),
array("attribute"=>"attribute_2","eq"=>"something")
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(
    array("attribute"=>"attribute_1","eq"=>"something"),
    array("attribute"=>"attribute_2","eq"=>"something")
    ));
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Thank you. It won't let me vote you up until I have 15 reputation points.

Comment: Correction. Doesn't work perfect. The exact same code that worked in sales_order_place_after observer isn't working in catalog_product_save_after or catalog_product_prepare_save observer. If I limit it to a single attribute, it works how it should. Don't understand why it would work in one place but not another.